# multiply a 2d array by a 1d array

Tags: java, arrays

I've initialized a 1d and 2d array and now I basically just want to be able to perform matrix multiplication on them. However, I'm not quite getting the proper answer. I think I've mixed up the for loop where I try to ensure I only multiply the correct values, but can't quite get the hang of it.

edit: I've fixed it, I was misunderstanding what the length method of a 2D array returned (thought it returned columns and not rows). The below code is my corrected code. Thanks everyone.

```
public static double[] getOutputArray(double[] array1D, double[][] array2D) {
    int oneDLength = array1D.length;
    int twoDLength = array2D[0].length;
    double[] newArray = new double[array2D[0].length]; // create the array that will contain the result of the array multiplication  
    for (int i = 0; i < twoDLength; i++) { // use nested loops to multiply the two arrays together
        double c = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < oneDLength; j++) {
            double l = array1D[j];
            double m = array2D[j][i];
            c += l * m; // sum the products of each set of elements
        }
        newArray[i] = c;
    }
    return newArray; // pass newArray to the main method
} // end of getOutputArray method
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have the ```i``` and ```j``` loops only do something if ```i == j```. Normally, you do a validation to make sure the dimensions are compatible, then do the work.

Comment: Your code has a number of issues (for example, you are setting every single element in `newArray` to `c` each time through the loop, and the `i==j` thing doesn't make much sense), and, while it is tempting to just give you the correct code, instead I recommend working this out on paper before implementing it. Each element `j` in the output array is equal to the sum of the products `array2D[j][i] * array1D[i]` over *i = 0 to oneDLength-1*, your primary issue is how you are accumulating those sums and storing them in the output array.

Comment: maybe this helpful for someone: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMultiplication.html

Comment: @JasonC Thanks! The part about ranging from 0 - oneDLength-1 cleared it all up! I was thinking that x.length of a 2D array gave me the number of columns and not rows, so I just took the length of one of the elements in the 2D array and it fixed everything. Thanks for all your help, I'll post my fixed code above.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems, first of all, you should decide how the vectors represented, are you multiplying from left or right.

For the maths: vector `1xn` times matrix `nxm` will result in `1xm`, while matrix `mxn` times `nx1` result in `mx1`.

I think the following would work for you:

```
public static double[] getOutputArray(double[] array1D, double[][] array2D) {
  int oneDLength = array1D.length;
  int twoDLength = array2D.length;
  double[] newArray = new double[twoDLength]; // create the array that will contain the result of the array multiplication
  assert twoDLength >0 && array2D[0].length == oneDLength;
  for (int i = 0; i < twoDLength; i++) { // use nested loops to multiply the two arrays together
      double c = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < oneDLength; j++) {
          double l = array1D[j];
          double m = array2D[i][j];
          c += l * m; // sum the products of each set of elements
      }
      newArray[i] = c;
   }
   return newArray; // pass newArray to the main method
} // end of getOutputArray method
```

I hope I did not make a mistake, while trying to fix.

Comment: You did make a mistake; you swapped a few `i`s and `j`s. For example, `array1D[i]` is not correct, as `i` is the loop on *twoDLength*, not *oneDLength*. `array2D[j][i]` suffers a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I have not checked those parts, just copy/pasted. I've fixed that.

Comment: Almost! You also want to reset `c` to 0 each time through; or just simplify and operate directly on `newArray[i]`.

Comment: @JasonC I guess I should just write it by myself instead of trying to fix it. The `l` and `m` identifiers are also confusing, those are usually integers in my code.

Comment: @GáborBakos Thanks for the help! I'm not familiar with assertions, but you're code helped me cut away some of the clutter I had in mine which let me catch my mistake. I was thinking that x.length of a 2D array gave the number of columns and not rows, and this was what was messing me up all along. Thanks!